# Spring MVC - Load bean definitions from appContext.xml programatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, gradle

I've been pulling my hair for hours on this one.

I am setting up a new Spring MVC REST servlet and I've been trying to avoid XML definitions this time and do it programatically.

To the problem: I am looking for a way to load bean definitions from applicationContext.xml while still having @ComponentScan(...) enabled (@Autowire/context.getBean(...) works in the latter).

I looked through the google trying countless combinations (I think, but I may have missed something) and found something that could help:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mixing-xml-and-javaconfig/
... only it doesn't (@ImportResource("classpath*:applicationContext")).

Please bear in mind that following declarations to @ImportResource fail the deployment of artifact (built with Gradle) with no log whatsoever:

- "applicationContext"
- "classpath:applicationContext"

The application context is located just next to 'java' folder (Gradle folder structure [src/main/java]):
[image]

My root config:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = { "com.storfoome.backend" },
        excludeFilters = {@Filter(classes = { Controller.class }, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)}
        )
public class ServiceRootConfig {
}
```

My web config:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = { "com.storfoome.backend" },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = { @Filter(classes = { Controller.class }, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION) }
        )
public class ServiceWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("*/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

My servlet initializer:

```java
import com.storfoome.backend.framework.rest.config.ServiceRootConfig;
import com.storfoome.backend.framework.rest.config.ServiceWebConfig;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SofomeServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private static final String DEFAULT_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/sofome/*";

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { ServiceRootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {ServiceWebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { DEFAULT_SERVLET_MAPPING };
    }
}
```

The bean with @Autowire from XML declared bean:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("autowireTest")
public class AutowireTest {
    @Autowired
    private SofomePropertyResource propertyResource;

    public void printProperty() {
        System.out.println(propertyResource.getProperty("helloWorld"));
    }

    public AutowireTest() {
    }

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

My applicationContext.xml:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="sofomeProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:sofome.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while I was posting this I also resolved this. So for anyone whould would be struggling with this.

Everything related to Java code in the question is correct apparently.

The thing was, with Gradle and it's "war" plugin. So, it looks into 'resource' folder by default for everything not *.java [citation needed].

I moved the applicationContext.xml to 'resource/config', launched Gradle build process (NOTE: I do not have any custom script written for WAR generation. Just "**apply plugin: 'war'**"):

[image]